# Is it possible to list or delete monday.com webhooks?

Tags: monday.com

I am using webhook integration to sync monday.com tasks' update, Unfortunately the baseUrl changed and I need to update the webhooks URL accordingly, Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following GraphQL will list existing webhooks.
This is documented on the Monday.com developer board: [Webhooks Queries](https://developer.monday.com/api-reference/docs/webhooks-1#webhooks-queries)

```
query {
  webhooks(board_id:1721464578){
    id
    event
    board_id
    config
  }
}
```

The following is GraphQL to delete specific webhooks by id.
This is documented on the Monday.com developer board: [Delete a webhook](https://developer.monday.com/api-reference/docs/webhooks-1#webhooks-mutations)

```
mutation {
    delete_webhook(id:12) {
        id
        board_id
    }
}
```

You can then create webhooks via GraphSQL shared on the Monday.com developer board: [Create a webhook](https://developer.monday.com/api-reference/docs/webhooks-1#webhooks-mutations)

A great tool is the [Monday.com API Playground](https://monday.com/developers/v2/try-it-yourself) where you can try all these queries out.

I have not yet found how to update a webhook via GraphQL.